# Media Server draining my phone battery?

Tags: applications

I noticed from yesterday that my phone is using 1% every 2 minutes.

From battery I can see Media Server with almost 70% consumption

The app can't be closed

What should I do please ?
*No I don't have microSD

Comment: What Media Server are you talking about?

Comment: This is what is called from battery consumption

Comment: Try to install an app list/info app that shows you the app name and the package name. Without the package name it is difficult to guess if this is a system app in an endless loop (e.g. caused by indexing a defect audio/video file) or malware that uses this name.

Comment: From app list I can't find the Media server

Comment: In Android settings you may have to enable the option to show system apps. The app list in Android settings doesn't show app package names. Therefore my recommendation is to use a third party app manager app from Play Store.

Comment: Today it disappeared and seems ok for now

Comment: Today it disappeared and seems ok for now